# Edittext in listview returns null for the last item

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a listView which contain edittext and checkboxes, my problem is that the edittext returns the last item in the list null, I want to hold the editable text of the last item and returns it, Any help please

Here is my getView code

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder=null;
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.check1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
            holder.check2 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check2);
            holder.note = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }
        holder.check1.setTag(position);
        holder.check2.setTag(position);
        final Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.note.setText(items.get(position).notes);
        holder.note.setId(position);

        holder.note.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    final int position = v.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    items.get(position).notes = Caption.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.textView1.setText(item.getName());
        holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if(buttonView.isPressed()){
                    if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                        Item p = items.get(position);
                        p.setSelectedcheck1(isChecked);
                        item.setFound(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        holder.check2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if(buttonView.isPressed()){
                    if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                        Item p = items.get(position);
                        p.setSelectedcheck2(isChecked);
                        item.setWorking(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        holder.check1.setChecked(item.isSelectedcheck1());
        holder.check2.setChecked(item.isSelectedcheck2());
        return itemView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView1;
    public CheckBox  check2,check1;
    EditText note;
}
}
```